# No internal adb?

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb, 7.0-nougat

I just got a Nexus 6p yesterday. Today I rooted it, with TWRP and Cyanogenmod 14.1. I have noticed that there is no command "adb" in /system/bin. I would like to know why, and how can I get it? My unrooted lollipop phone does have it.

Comment: Why do you need that? My MM device doesn't have it. Try looking in folder system/xbin/ if there isn't then try to update/install busybox (most custom roms doesn't have it preinstalled).

Comment: Where can I get an *up to date* version of busybox that has the adb? I want it to run commands on my friends phone.

Comment: I don't know for sure if there is in busybox but I assume there is because my old phone with CM 10.1 and busybox does have it. You can install/update busybox with app "BusyBox" from play store (root requiered)

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I just tried it

Comment: What doesn't work, did you updated it from BusyBox app?

Comment: Never mind about this. Thanks for trying to help

Comment: I found that ADB command was removed in 6.0 and it seems it didn't come back with 7.0. You'll probably need to find other way to do what you intended to.

Comment: many android apps were using local `adb` client to gain `shell` user privileges - so it was deemed a security threat and it has been removed.